# Trying to ping linux vm hosted on azure does not work

Tags: linux, azure, virtual-machine, ping, icmp

As title, how can I ping my machine to do some basic network testing? I have created a new VM but pinging it's public address returns request timeout.

Comment: Check your firewall settings. May be it is blocking your IP.

Answer (score 5):

Ping is blocked by default for Azure VMs for security reasons ([source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_azure_guide/archive/2014/12/13/how-to-allow-ping-functionality-to-windows-azure-machines.aspx)). You could either [`allow ICMP by configuring appropriate firewall rules`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_azure_guide/archive/2014/12/13/how-to-allow-ping-functionality-to-windows-azure-machines.aspx) or [`Use port pings instead of ICMP to test Azure VM connectivity`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mast/archive/2014/06/22/use-port-pings-instead-of-icmp-to-test-azure-vm-connectivity.aspx).

Comment: This answer doesn't allow the Internet to ping the VM successfully, only other VM's in the VM's Vnet.