# Speed of Azure Dreamspark plan

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, dreamspark

Is it normal, that Azure running free Dreamspark plan is so slow, that pinging through cmd on Windows shows that all send packets were lost? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: "Or am I doing something wrong" — what are you doing? :)

Comment: `that pinging through cmd on Windows shows that all send packets were lost?` - Please note that `ping` cmd is blocked by default for Azure resources. Please see this thread for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34669632/trying-to-ping-linux-vm-hosted-on-azure-does-not-work.

Answer (score 2):

[Dreamspark](https://www.dreamspark.com/) is a program that grants you access to  [Azure](https://www.dreamspark.com/Product/Product.aspx?productid=99), is not a service in itself.

If you are using Azure Web Apps, the fact that you created the service through a Dreamspark-type subscription has nothing to do with the service performance.

Web app performance is tied to your app code, the [pricing/performance tier](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/), and things like your traffic and instance number (among other things).

By default, you cannot PING an Azure Web App for security reasons. If you want to test site availability or geolocation response times, you can [use App Insights to create your Availability Test](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-monitor-web-app-availability/).

Furthermore, [App Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-asp-net/) or [NewRelic](http://newrelic.com/azure) are profiling tools you can use to find performance bottleneck in your code or resource consumption.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, I didn't write precisely, what I'm thinking of. I installed Wordpress from Azure Marketplace,  and tested performance with z-ray. It showed me, that on free performance tier, it requires 30 sec to load the page. Is it normal?

Comment: Ok, there are 2 important things. The first is that the Free tier runs on shared resources, it's good for testing purposes or small sites with minimal traffic. The second is, your first request on a fresh installed app can sometimes be slower than the rest (called a "cold-start"). You might want to check this list for [Wordpress performance tips on Azure](https://sunithamk.wordpress.com/2014/08/01/10-ways-to-speed-up-your-wordpress-site-on-azure-websites/).