# Why I can't ping Azure VM from my local PC

Tags: windows, azure, ping, azure-virtual-machine

I have a Windows VM on Azure and I don't understand why my **ping times out**.
I found a probable reason: on Azure portal I see public IP "40.127.163.20", but inside VM when I do ipconfig I see different IP that is strange.

Do you have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: See if this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34669632/trying-to-ping-linux-vm-hosted-on-azure-does-not-work.

Comment: Also, there's [this answer](http://serverfault.com/a/749429/99269) on ServerFault (where this type of question actually belongs). It's been answered several times there.

Comment: Gaurav Mantri, no it doesn't answer my question.. I can ping websites from inside my VM except VM public IP address..

Comment: David Makogon - it doesn't answer my question.. I need to access my website through IP or DNS name, but I can't do it for some reasons..

Comment: http://www.letmecheck.it/tcp-ping.php TCP based ping

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ICMP protocol is not permitted through the Azure load balancer (inbound or outbound) which means that you can't do a simple ping to your VM. There is a : [user voice request for this to be enabled here.](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking-dns-traffic-manager-vpn-vnet/suggestions/3346609-icmp-support-for-azure-websites-roles-cloud-serv?page=3&per_page=20)

[This blog here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mast/archive/2014/06/22/use-port-pings-instead-of-icmp-to-test-azure-vm-connectivity.aspx) describes how you can use a port ping as an alternative.

There is [some documentation on how to set up an Instance Level IP](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-instance-level-public-ip/), which would circumnavigate the load balancer and give direct communication to the Virtual Machine, but I haven't tried this approach (I'm giving it a go right now, will report back)

Comment: Hi Martin, is there any documentation on MSDN which means about ping disabled in Azure VM by default? Thanks

Comment: Hello, unfortunatelly it's not my case since I can ping websites inside my VM by IP or DNS. Do you have any assumptions?