# Can not ping to Azure VM

Tags: azure, ubuntu-14.04, azure-virtual-machine

I have created a VM on azure from the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Canonical image. I can ssh to the public IP. I have added an inbound security rule for: http port (80), source: any, action: allow.

I am trying to use psping to ping to the port (since Azure does not allow regular pings):

psing [my ip here]:80

I see a bunch of " The remote computer refused the network connection." prints.

What else do I need to do to make sure port 80 is accessible publicly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to ping linux vm hosted on azure does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34669632/trying-to-ping-linux-vm-hosted-on-azure-does-not-work)

Comment: Well, is there anything listening on TCP/80 in that VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **The remote computer refused the network connection.**

According to the error, you need check whether your app is running firstly.Based on my experience, if Azure NSG or Firewall block the port 80, you should get error `Request timed out`.

You could use `netstat -ant|grep 80` Please ensure port 80 is listening like below:

`tcp       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN`

Note: **port 80 should listening on tcp not tcp6**.

Also, you could use `telnet` to check whether the port 80 is open on your public IP.

`telnet yourip 80`

Answer (score 1):

Generally, there are 2 reasons for this to fail:
- Network Security Group must allow port 80 to be accessible
- Firewall on the VM itself must allow port 80 to be accessible
- Application must be listening on port 80

If anything of those is not in place the attempt to connect to port 80 will fail.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that the webserver was not allowing connections from anyone else other than localhost.

I used the following tools to check things:

To check if local firewall is working: ufw status
To check if webserver is really running: wget localhost:80
To check if the server is generally accessible (psping the ssh port): psping server_ip:22